# python arraylist distribution

Tags: arrays, python-2.7

```
  def createlist(json, filename, arraygroup):
  filehdl = open(filename, "wb")

  for key, value in rulegroup.items():
      filehdl.write('#' + value + "\n")
      for list in json:
          if list['arraygroup'] == value:
          filehdl.write(list['name'] + " " + list['surname'] + "\n")

  filehdl.close()

#depart1
testname testsurname
testname1 testsurname2
testname3 testsurname3

#depart2
#depart3

Json has 5 names, and 2 names should be places in #depart2, #depart3 base on their correct department.
```

Hi i have here a code that will create a file and separate the names in json file base on there group, but the 2nd forloop (with json) was not resetting its index, so after 1st loop of the forloop list was stuck.

tnx for answer.^^,

Answer (score 0):

I already resolve the problem by inputing json obj to array.

```
    jsonlist = []  
    for obj in json:
        jsonlist.append(obj)
```

then change the 2nd loop with jsonlist

```
for list in jsonlist:
      if list['arraygroup'] == value:
      filehdl.write(list['name'] + " " + list['surname'] + "\n")
```